# could not instantiate RegionFactory

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I am trying to enable secondary cache, but i am getting exception.

Code for secondary cache in persistence.xml is given below:

```
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.EhCache"/>
        </properties>
```

Stacktrace for exception is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.org.JPAUtil.<clinit>(JPAUtil.java:21)
    at com.org.Main.main(Main.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/ehcache/CacheException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2404)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2714)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1674)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createRegionFactory(SettingsFactory.java:409)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:280)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2833)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2829)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1840)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:902)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:57)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:48)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:32)
    at com.org.JPAUtil.<clinit>(JPAUtil.java:17)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 20 more
```

After adding jar for ehcache, I'm getting exception as

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not instantiate RegionFactory [org.hibernate.cache.EhCache]
at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createRegionFactory(SettingsFactory.java:423)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:280)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2833)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2829)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1840)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:902)
... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: org.hibernate.cache.EhCache
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createRegionFactory(SettingsFactory.java:419)
    ... 15 more
```

Comment: Which version of hibernate are you using?

Comment: Which hibernate libraries do you have added to your classpath?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of:

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.EhCache"/>
```

Use:

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class"  value="org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider"/>
```

For example, using Hibernate 4.x along with the JAR files [hibernate-ehcache-4.3.10.Final.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-ehcache/4.3.10.Final) and [slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.6.1), modify `persistence.xml`:

```
<properties>
  <!-- ... other properties ... -->
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
  <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>
  <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
  <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class"  value="org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider"/>
</properties>
```

Then ensure that `hibernate-ehcache-4.3.10.Final.jar` and `slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar` are deployed to JBoss.

> Do **not** include `ehcache-core-2.4.3.jar`.

Now you can annotate entities, such as:

```
@Entity
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL, region = "region_name")
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: I'd all implementation right except, instead of using property name of "factory_class", I had to use "provider_class".
Feel free to edit or add new answer describing this. I'll make it accepted answer :-) [I'm not sure yet why factory_class didn't work.]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `Hibernate` and `ehcache` are in the same directory. Either application server  `lib` or your application `WEB-INF/lib`

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the `ehcache-x.x.jar` is in your classpath. In eclipse, you can check it by `right click your project -> build path -> configure build path`. If you missed that jar, you can download it from [here](http://www.findjar.com/class/net/sf/ehcache/CacheException.html;jsessionid=89E972781727367385544AEB0519ED4B). If you are using maven, you can just put the following dependency in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I've added jar for ehcache, now i'm getting another exception. (edited in question)

Comment: you might require to add type as pom after version

Answer (score 0):

Use the below property in your persistence.xml.

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>
```

It will resolve the issue.